# VBA - master password + three users passwords

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba, passwords

I googled already but cannot find a VBA for this simple question: For the workbook, possible to create one Admin pw and three User passwords? Example:

Workbook named "Finance" is fully protected by the Admin (me).
There are three users that need to view/input data into limited number of cells.
Of course, those cells are unprotected but everything else protected.

```
Admin pw = snowwhite  <<< Essentially, this is the master pw.
John pw = dwarf1  <<< User limited view/input into certain cells.
Lisa pw = dwarf2  <<< User limited view/input into certain cells.
Sam pw = dwarf3  <<< User limited view/input into certain cells.
```

Is it possible to create an Admin pw for the workbook and create three users’ passwords for three different users? Each user has the exact same view/limitations, for now.

Also, is it possible to allow the three users to change their pw, but the macro is able to capture their new pw, for which the Admin can see when he uses the master pw (snowwhite) to enter the workbook.

I was terrible at explaining in my previous questions, but I hope I did a better job this time.

Comment: No. There is no built in way for that. Of course you can create a macro to manage access rights, but for that complexity maybe Excel is not the right tool.

Comment: If the admin and three users are four distinct Windows logins, then you may give the three users read-only permissions on the file and password changes will not apply.